# Having two different Customer Types in a Database

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

My system needs two different Customer Types. I need an Individual and Corporate Customer. How would I go about creating the tables in Apex?

Do  I need a Customer, Individual and Corporate table or just a Customer and Corporate table?

This system is for a Car Hire.

The attributes I would need are: Customer ID, First Name, Surname, Address, Post Code, Phone Number, Corporate Name, Frequency (this is for the Corporate entity based on how regularly they hire).

Comment: You could always just have a big table with columns for private and corporate customers. Or you could separate it out as MT0 suggested, or you could do a dozen different things. You need to find a compromise between a few tables and many columns and many tables and a few columns. You don't want to make a god table, but you also don't want to make a dozen tables when just two or three would suffice.
This is all a matter of business needs and complexity of code for you, so its gonna be up to you to decide how to separate the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A corporation name belongs to the corporation not to an individual customer; so create a `Corporations` table and then reference that in a foreign key for your corporate customers. You can also separate out the core `Customer` data from the `CorporateCustomer` data and store these in separate tables:

**Oracle 18c Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Customers (
  id           NUMBER(10,0)
               GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
               CONSTRAINT Customers__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name   VARCHAR2(200)
               CONSTRAINT Customers__firstname__nn NOT NULL,
  surname      VARCHAR2(200)
               CONSTRAINT Customers__surname__nn NOT NULL,
  post_code    VARCHAR2(7)
               CONSTRAINT Customers__postcode__nn NOT NULL,
  phone_number VARCHAR2(15)
               CONSTRAINT Customers__phone__nn NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Corporations(
  id           NUMBER(10,0)
               GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
               CONSTRAINT Corporations__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  name         VARCHAR2(500)
               CONSTRAINT Corporations__name__nn NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Corporate_Customers (
  id           NUMBER(10,0)
               CONSTRAINT CorporateCustomers__id__pk PRIMARY KEY
               CONSTRAINT CorporateCustomers__id__fk REFERENCES Customers(id),
  corporation  NUMBER(10,0)
               CONSTRAINT CorporateCustomers__corp__nn NOT NULL
               CONSTRAINT CorporateCustomers__corp__fk REFERENCES Corporations(id),
  frequency    NUMBER(10,0)
               CONSTRAINT CorporateCustomers__freq__nn NOT NULL
               CONSTRAINT CorporateCustomers__freq_gte_0__chk CHECK ( frequency >= 0 )
);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=de27abb0d61f033614687399c4065a55)